# How to plot a 3_d representation of the probability density function in the bloch sphere?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, scipy, probability

I have a model which gives me datasets in a specific form. Lets say its a radius + 2 angles (r,phi,theta). I would like to plot this data in the bloch sphere with two volumes indicating the regions where 25% or 75% of the data points are lying.

Here an example of what I would like to visualize in 2D.

[image: Here an example of what I would like to visualize in 2D.]

My idea was to:

1. Bin the 3D data with np.histogramdd

   ```
   # transform my data onto a cartesian coordinate system
   X = amp * np.sin(2*chi) * np.cos(theta)
   Y = amp * np.sin(2*chi) * np.sin(theta)
   Z = amp * np.cos(2*chi)

   data_xyz=np.array([X,Y,Z]).T

   hist, binedges = np.histogramdd(data_xyz,bins=60, normed=False)


   list_of_weighted_entries = np.sort(np.reshape(hist,np.power(60,3)))
   weight_sum = np.sum(hist)
   ```
2. Reshape the binned data so that I get a list with descending order of the weighted indexes and define the threshold (25 or 75 %) to define which indexes are inside the specific pdf volume :

   ```
   #For 25 %
   cumu_weight = 0
   index = 1
   while cumu_weight < weight_sum * 0.25:
       cumu_weight = cumu_weight + list_of_weighted_entries[-index]
       index = index + 1

   treshhold_value = list_of_weighted_entries[-(index-1)]
   ```
3. Using marching cubes to plot those volumes

   ```
   #calculate the bin_size for each direction
   diff0 = binedges[0][1] - binedges[0][0]
   diff1 = binedges[1][1] - binedges[1][0]
   diff2 = binedges[2][1] - binedges[2][0]

   verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(hist, treshhold_value,(diff0,diff1,diff2))

   fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
   ax   = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
   mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces],linewidths=0,facecolor="rosybrown")
   mesh.set_edgecolor('k')
   ax.add_collection3d(mesh)
   ```
4. Add some plotting styles etc....

   This gives me a quite nice image but something goes wrong as the volume should not be outside the transparent sphere+ it is rotated. Somewhere in the transformation from the bins back to the coordinates I seem to mess up.

Does someone have an idea where?

EDIT: I'm now quite sure that the problem lies in `Poly3DCollection` plotting. The thing is that this plot always starts at 0:0:0 but the coordinates I give histogramm function also have negative volumes-> I have to add a translation to the data I get after calculating my "PDF volumes"

This gives me a quite nice image but something goes wrong as the volume should not be outside the transparent sphere (as the radius of the sphere is 1.1 times the max radius).

[image]